# reset an origin to a certain commit

Tags: javascript, git, github, branch, reset

I, for mistake pushed a branch 'dev' to my 'origin/dev' in the repository, so now i would like to reset those branches to this commit 226b5cf7.

i already tried this:
git reset --hard 226b5cf7  (so now my dev is reset to that commit)
git push --force origin 226b5cf7:dev  (to reset origin/dev, BUT NOT WORKING!!!)

i get this message:
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/dev (you should pull first)
To ssh://demadev/volume1/Git/smile.git
 ! [remote rejected] 226b5cf7 -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://codinera@demadev/volume1/Git/smile.git'

Comment: `git checkout -b tmp origin/dev; git reset --hard 226b5cf7; git push -f origin HEAD:dev; git checkout dev; git branch -D tmp;` (you need to choose another name if you have already *tmp* branch present)

Answer (score 1):

> i already tried this: `git reset --hard 226b5cf7` (so now my `dev` is reset to that commit)

This is fine, but not technically necessary.  Note that you would first have to `git checkout dev` to make this affect your name `dev`.

> [followed by] `git push --force origin 226b5cf7:dev` (to reset origin/dev, BUT NOT WORKING!!!)

This is the part that is required.

You say it is "not working".  If you are also saying that the result of this command, including the `--force` option, is:

> ```
> remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/dev (you should pull first)
> To ssh://demadev/volume1/Git/smile.git
>   ! [remote rejected] 226b5cf7 -> dev (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://codinera@demadev/volume1/Git/smile.git'
> ```

then this means that they—the Git at `codinera@demadev/volume1/Git/smile.git`—are ignoring your force option and *still* refusing to make the change you requested.  (This would be the normal response to an attempt *without* the `--force` flag.)

If this is the case, there is no way for you to make this change directly.  You will have to find someone who *does* have permission to make the change, make the change.  This may involve logging in on the machine named `demadev`.  The Git repository there may have `receive.denyNonFastForwards` set to `true`.

Comment: Thank you... yes i think i don't have the permission to do that

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot do it due to the permissions on the remote node, there is another way: restore the old state of the the commit and push it as a new commit.

This command will checkout all files in from your commit into the current dirctory.

```
git checkout  226b5cf7 -- .
```

It will not remove newly created files though. You need to find them by diffing file lists against the reset then and remove manually.

```
git diff 226b5cf7  --name-status
```

Now you can commit and push.

Then you can restore your state before update in a similar manner to be able to push it later.